# Three questions about atexit

Tags: c++, c, exit, atexit

RETURN VALUE:

```
   The atexit() function returns the value 0 if successful; otherwise, it returns a nonzero value.
```

EXAMPLE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void
bye(void)
{
    printf("That was all, folks\n");
}

int
main(void)
{
    long a;
    int i;

    a = sysconf(_SC_ATEXIT_MAX);
    printf("ATEXIT_MAX = %ld\n", a);

    i = atexit(bye);
    if (i != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot set exit function\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I have read manual page and StackOverflow questions, but still, have three questions about `atexit`:

1. When will `atexit` fail, so it will return the non-zero value? please give me such a demo, thanks!
2. as we know, `bye` will not be called until exit() is called. So does it mean we can not know `atexit`'s return value until exit() is called? if it is, then the third question:
3. Now that exit() has been called, how can the `if` expression be executed?

Comment: `atexit` is not required to be able to store an infinite number of function  pointers, so it might return an error code if running out of memory.

Comment: Read http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/atexit

Comment: "I have read manual page and StackOverflow questions" - congratulations. You are already in the top 1% of developers!

Comment: `atexit` simply registers a function to be called as part of exit handlers. Its return value is whether that registration has been successful; not the return value of the function it registered; registered functions are NOT called by `atexit`; they'll be called when the program exits (normally).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`atexit()` registers a function to be called at program exit, but it completes its execution and returns control to the calling context, without waiting for program termination. In other words it doesn't suspend program execution, if not for the time to register the function passed. The program will then resume from where `atexit()` was called, and only when it will terminate for whatever reason, the registered handler will be called.

This should answer your question 2: `atexit()` returns a value "immediately", not at program termination. This should also answer your question 3: `exit()` is not called when you call `atexit()`, and the program flow can continue as normal.

Regarding your first question, the conditions upon which `atexit()` can fail depend on the particular libc implementation. In those cases a negative value will be returned and `errno` will contain a code reflecting the error condition. For example, in GNU libc atexit() returns with an error if it cannot allocate an entry for the passed error function, see the [__new_exitfn() source code](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/stdlib/cxa_atexit.c.html#__new_exitfn), called internally by `atexit` ([source code here](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/stdlib/atexit.c.html)).

Answer (score 3):

> as we know, `bye` will not be called until exit() is called. So does it mean we can not know `atexit`'s return value until exit() is called?

I'm not sure I can exactly follow your thoughts, but the misconception seems to be just the following:

`atexit()` reporting success simply means "I accepted whatever pointer you gave me, the function it points to will be called at exit". This doesn't mean the actual **call** to your function will be successful.

`atexit()` reporting error therefore means: "For whatever reason, I couldn't accept your pointer". Your runtime environment might be out of memory to store another pointer or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

The `atexit` function just adds the function to a "list". It will not itself call the function you pass a pointer to. It will also not wait for `exit` to be called, as that would make it rather useless. Therefore it can return (with a possible error code) immediately, and the program continues as normal.

If the function fails to add the function pointer you pass to its internal "list" (for example it might be a limited size, and you attempt to add more than that) then it will return with a failure. Again, it will return immediately and not wait for an `exit` call.

Answer (score 2):

in regards to question 1: `atexit` only sets a function *to be called* on exit. It returns 0 as long as it was able to *set* that function, regardless of whether that function has actually been called yet.

So that answers your Question 2 and 3: no, you do not need to wait for `exit()` to know the return of `atexit`, so evaluating the `if` is no problem either.